# How to slice values inside variable slice with space using javascript and place all values in separate variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have varaible which hold value like this var  item_size=74X80(space here)30 i.e in browser it looks like    "74x80     30" I want to divide it place in separate varaible

i. var a=74X80;
ii. var b=30;

so after slicing with space it should assign values into separate variable using javascript

```
<script>

var item_size = item_size.split(" ");

  alert(item_size[1]);
   alert(item_size[2]);

</script>
```

Comment: Arrays are zero-indexed in Javascript. Is the first `alert` displaying `30` as expected?

Comment: @Mohammad - Unfortunately, your edit adding a snippet makes a very large assumption the question isn't clear enough for us to be sure of.

Comment: @ anonymous - Please use the "edit" link to show us **exactly** what you mean by *"var item_size=74X80(space here)30 i.e in browser it looks like "74x80 30""* so we aren't guessing. Your description sounds like a syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

```
var item_size = "74X80 30";
item_size = item_size.split(" ");

alert(item_size[0]);
alert(item_size[1]);

console.log(a); 
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ES6 array destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
var [a,b] = '74X80 30'.split(' ')

console.log(a)
console.log(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Accessing array elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Accessing_array_elements)

> JavaScript arrays are zero-indexed: the first element of an array is at *index* 0, and the last element is at the *index* equal to the value of the array's *length* property minus 1. Using an invalid *index* number returns `undefined`.

You have to use `0` to access the first element, `1` to access the second element an so on....:

```js
var item_size = "74X80 30";
item_size = item_size.split(" ");

alert(item_size[0]);
alert(item_size[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are zero indexed - so you need

```js
var  item_size="74X80 30";
var item_size_portions = item_size.split(" ");

var a = item_size_portions[0];
var b = item_size_portions[1];

console.log(a); // gives 74X80;
console.log(b); // gives 30;
```